# flask python -Extract json data whose sent in post method

Tags: python, flask, post

I need to extract the object whose sent as json
I have this code whose brings me the json in object called content

```
  @app.route('/AddMessage', methods = ['POST'])
  def AddMessage():
    print (request.is_json)
    content = request.get_json()
    print (content)
    return 'JSON posted'
```

I want to acheive the property of data.

The data I sent is:

```
   {
     "device": "TemperatureSensor",
      "value": "20",
     "timestamp": "25/01/2017 10:10:05"
   }
```

so I want the value of 'device'.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have right now? What's not working?

Comment: this works well, but I want to get the value of 'device' that is 'TemperatureSensor'. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `content['device']`  - `get_json()` returns a dict

Comment: thanks, it helps me a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the content type of your request is `application/json`, `request.get_json()` will return a dictionary that corresponds to your JSON structure. (For other content types it will return `None`.)

This means that you can access the value of *device* with

```
content = request.get_json()
device = content["device"]
```